# Google charts table - stack columns

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-visualization

Here is a screenshot of a Google Charts table I have made that reads from a Google Sheet:

[image]

I also have the html doc hosted on the Google Cloud Platform [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/asl-mobile-app/Responsibility%20Matrix%20Tool.html)

I would like the columns to be stacked vertically, is this possible? So visually there would only be one column (I will remove the option to select multiple values).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are no options for stacking columns in a table chart,
but you could draw multiple table charts, one for each column.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['controls','corechart','table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

function drawDashboard() {
    var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A,B,C,D');

    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
            'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J_xPpcXW9SS_u9bxCDwwFtCHpbW8NFX97vaav8YRMQc/gviz/tq?gid=2068570642&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);

}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();

    var cssClassNames = {
        'headerCell': 'headcell'
    };

    var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'categorySelector',
        'state': {'selectedValues': ['KwaMashu Cemetery - Queries on Visitor Access']},
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Search Field',
            'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': true,
                'allowMultiple': true,
                'allowNone': true,
                'label': 'Search for an Open Space'
            }
        }
    });

    var tables = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        addTable(i);
    }

    function addTable(index) {
        var table = document.getElementById('tables').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        table.id = 'table-' + index;
        tables.push(new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'Table',
            'containerId': 'table-' + index,
            'options': {cssClassNames: cssClassNames, allowHTML: true, width: '100%'},
            'view': {
              columns: [index]
            }
        }));
    }

    // Create a dashboard
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
        document.getElementById('dashboard1')
    );
    dashboard.bind(categoryPicker, tables);

    dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```css
.goog-menu-vertical {overflow-y:scroll; max-height:200px}

th {
    background-color: #33338b;
    color: white;
}
    .headcell {}

body {
    background: #ffffff;
}

.panel {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
    <div id="dashboard1">
        <div id="categorySelector"></div>
        <br>
        <div id="tables"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```